# MongoDB most simple usage of $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get all objects matching a filter from several collections to an aggregation's result set. The approach is probably the $lookup stage. In the documentation as well as in samples I found yet it is described like this:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

I don't want the $lookup to do any filters and I don't want to access any specific fields and I don't want to get an output array. All these $lookup fields seem to be mandatory and lead into results I don't need.

How can I just simply get all documents of one collection, then add all documents of another collection, etc. until I add the final aggregation stage (in my case a sort)?

Background: I have several collections with identically structured data, could be named like "Jobs.Current", "Jobs.Finished". My aggregation query wants to consider data from both collections and sort them after having it all in one aggregation result set.

Comment: Can you update your question with a specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Add some sample data, otherwise its difficult to find what you expected

Comment: The actual layout of data doesn't matter here as I want to leave and get the matched documents as they are after the $match and $project stages.